# Passing variable to SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD

Tags: db2

I have a bit of a problem whereby I need to pass a variable value to SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD.

Here is the deal:

```
DECLARE vDate   TIMESTAMP;
SET vDate = timestamp_iso (MyDateFunctionGoesHere());

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('LOAD FROM (select vDate...) OF CURSOR insert into ..  (DateColumn...) NONRECOVERABLE');
```

The problem is that the upon running the Stored Procedure, I get error:

> ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0206N  "VDATE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

I tried modifying it to:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('LOAD FROM (select'''||vDate||'''...) OF CURSOR insert into ..  (DateColumn...) NONRECOVERABLE');
```

Then I get "no authorized routine named || of type FUNCTION...

I need my date variable to passed to the LOAD from because this is a dynamic value that changes all the time. How can I handle that?

Comment: Concatenation (that's the `|| of type FUNCTION`) works on strings, not timestamps. You may want to try `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` instead of `TIMESTAMP_ISO()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ADMIN_CMD` takes one argument that is a string, it's easiest to build your SQL statement as a VARCHAR, and then pass that variable to `ADMIN_CMD`. Setting `vDate` is unnecessary.

```
DECLARE vCMD    VARCHAR(1024);

SET vCMD = 'LOAD FROM (select ' || CHAR(MyDateFunctionGoesHere()) || '...) OF CURSOR insert into ..  (DateColumn...) NONRECOVERABLE';

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD (vSQL);
```

Note that I'm assuming `MyDateFunctionGoesHere()` returns a `TIMESTAMP`, and using `CHAR()` to convert it to `CHAR(26)` to concatenate it.